# How to send different parameters to the same function? (laravel 5.3)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

My view is like this :

```
...
<a class="btn btn-primary pull-right" style="margin-top: -10px;margin-bottom: 5px" href="{!! route('users.create.year', [$year]) !!}">
    Add New
</a>
...

...
@foreach($testArray as $key)
...
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" href="{!! route('users.create.display.year', [$key['display'], $year]) !!}">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
</a>
...
@endforeach
...
```

My routes is like this :

```
Route::get('users/create/{year}', 'UserController@create')
     ->name('users.create.year');

Route::get('users/create/{display}/{year}', 'UserController@create')
     ->name('users.create.display.year');
```

My controller is like this :

```
public function create($display = null, $year)
{
    echo $display;
    echo $year;die();
    ...
}
```

When I call url like this : `http://localhost/mysystem/public/users/create/2016`

There exist error like this :

```
 1/1 ErrorException in UserController.php line 314: 
 Missing argument 2 for App\Http\Controllers\UserController::create()
```

When I call url like this : `http://localhost/mysystem/public/users/create`/14144499452111901/2016`
The result is like this :

```
14144499452111901
2016
```

Why when I call a url with one parameter there is an error?

Comment: In my opinion, if `users/create/2016` is a valid link, then the other link should be `users/create/2016/14144499452111901`, not the other way around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [optional parameters](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/routing#parameters-optional-parameters) feature:

```
Route::get('users/create/{year}/{display?}', 'UserController@create')->name('users.create.year');
```

Use just one method, but with optional parameter:

```
public function create($year, $display = null)
```

Comment: There exist error like this : `Route [users.create.display.year] not defined. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\mysystem\resources\views\users\table.blade.php) (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\mysystem\resources\views\users\table.blade.php)`

Comment: As I said before you need only one method and one route. You get the error because you're using route name which didn't exist. Use `users.create.year` route everywhere.

Comment: Ok. There was no error but its results a little strange. Results: `2016
14144499452111901`. Should result `14144499452111901
2016`

Comment: I've changed year and display order in the route definition. I'm not sure if optional parameters will work if you put optional parameter before non-optional one. But you can try to do that if order is so important.

Answer (score 0):

```
Route::get('users/create/{year}', 'UserController@create')
     ->name('users.create.year');

Route::get('users/create/{display}/{year}', 'UserController@create')
     ->name('users.create.display.year');
```

You have defined two routes here and only one controller.

```
public function create($display = null, $year)
{
    echo $display;
    echo $year;die();
    ...
}
```

So when you do something like this `http://localhost/mysystem/public/users/create/2016`

it sends to the one that has more than one parameter.

Solution would be to create two controllers , one for each route

```
public function create($display = null, $year)
{
    echo $display;
    echo $year;die();
    ...
}

public function create( $year)
{
    echo $display;
    echo $year;die();
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use the Request object in the controller

`public function create(Request $request) 
 {
      $request->year;
    ...
 }`